# Datatable with Parent and Child to JSON format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, linq, datatable

I am trying to build a JSON output from the C# datatable. The single datatable contains parent and child as well. I would like to use LINQ to setup the JSON data, but would like to avoid creating classes since I have many such requirements and creating classes for each will be a burden.

[image]

The JSON output should be

```
{
Sports : [
{item: 'Porsche 911', quantity: 100},
{item: 'Porsche 912', quantity: 200}
],
Luxury : [
{item: 'BMW 3 Series', quantity: 300}
],
Small :[
{item: 'Toyota Corolla', quantity: 400},
{item: 'Mitsubishi Lancer', quantity: 500},
{item: 'Mitsubishi Lancer 2', quantity: 600}
]}
```

Sample code I tried

```
//get current stock
            DataTable dtCurrentStock = inventoryReports.getCurrentStock(currentDate);

            //get distinct item group
            DataTable dtItemGroup = dtCurrentStock.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "HEAD");

            DataSet sd = new DataSet();

            var itemGroup = dtItemGroup.AsEnumerable();
            var items = dtCurrentStock.AsEnumerable();

            var result = itemGroup.Select(group => new {
                groupName = group.Field<string>("HEAD"),
                itemDetl = 
                items.
                Where(item => (item.Field<string>("HEAD") == group.Field<string>("HEAD"))).
                Select(detl => new
                {
                    a = detl.ToString()
                })//.ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

**error**

```
Results View = The type '<>f__AnonymousType0<a>' exists in both 'APP-SERVICE.dll' and 'CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary'
```

Please provide a better code if available. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Along with existing table, I created another table with distinct HEAD. And tried to use LINQ, but I got error Results View = The type '<>f__AnonymousType0<a>' exists in both 'APP-SERVICE.dll' and 'CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary'. I did not want to post my code since I was expecting a better code. I will post if you require.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of Linq

```
var obj = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r["Head"])
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.ToString(),
                          g => g.Select(r => new {
                                                item = r["Item"].ToString(),
                                                quantity = (int)r["Quantity"]
                                             })
                                .ToArray());

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works great. Can I request you for a change? I want output to be{Head: 'Sports', Total: 300, data : [ {item: 'Porsche 911', quantity: 100}, {item: 'Porsche 912', quantity: 200}]}. Could you please help? I will try to learn based on your code. Thanks!

Comment: @VyasRao One question at a time please. If you have further questions, ask a new question.

Comment: New question opened, could you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32398821/datatable-with-parent-and-child-to-json-format-with-hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't have access to JsonConvert I propose standard System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lst = new ListOfMachines();
        lst.Add(new MachineInfo { Head = "Sports", Item = "Porshe 911", Quantity = 100 });
        lst.Add(new MachineInfo { Head = "Sports", Item = "Porshe 912", Quantity = 200 });
        lst.Add(new MachineInfo { Head = "Luxury", Item = "BMW 3 Series", Quantity = 300 });
        lst.Add(new MachineInfo { Head = "Small", Item = "Toyouta Corolla", Quantity = 400 });
        lst.Add(new MachineInfo { Head = "Small", Item = "Mitsubish Lancer", Quantity = 500 });
        lst.Add(new MachineInfo { Head = "Small", Item = "Mitsubish Lancer 2", Quantity = 600 });

        var json = lst.ToJson();

    }
}

public class ListOfMachines : List<MachineInfo>
{
    public string ToJson()
    {
        var initialGroupBy = this.GroupBy(a => a.Head,
                                            t => new { item = t.Item,
                                                quantity = t.Quantity}               
            ).ToDictionary(
                k => k.Key,
                s => s.Select(v => new {
                        item = v.item,
                        quantity = v.quantity
                }));

        var javaScriptSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(initialGroupBy);
        return jsonString;
    }
}   

public class MachineInfo
{
    public string Head { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

This code gives following output:

```
  {
    "Sports":[{"item":"Porshe 911","quantity":100},{"item":"Porshe      912","quantity":200}],
"Luxury":[{"item":"BMW 3 Series","quantity":300}],
"Small":[{"item":"Toyouta Corolla","quantity":400},{"item":"Mitsubish Lancer","quantity":500},{"item":"Mitsubish Lancer 2","quantity":600}]
```

}

Comment: Your code must work fine, but I do not wanted to create another class. The reason being I have to create many such JSON objects and it makes the code messy.